# angular form set up correctly yet form value not being passed

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have the following form defined in my html:

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2">
  <form (ngSubmit)="addswingtype()" #addswingtypeform="ngForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 mt-2">
         <input type="text"
                id="addswingtype"
                name="addswing"
                ngModel
                placeholder="Enter A Swing Type"
                class="form-control">

       </div>
       <div class="col-2 mt-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and then the following in my ts file:

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
    @ViewChild('addswingtypeform') addswingtypeform:NgForm;

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-swingerandhosttypes',
  templateUrl: './swingerandhosttypes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swingerandhosttypes.component.css'],
  providers: [Httpservice]
})
export class SwingerandhosttypesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Httpservice) { }

      addswingtype(){
        console.log(this.addswingtypeform);
       const url = swingtypeallorcreate;
       const payload = {
         name: this.addswingtypeform.form.value.addswing
       };
       this.http.post(url, payload)
         .subscribe(
           (req: any)=>{
             this.swingtypes.push(req);
           }
         );
      }
```

looks like correct code right? Well because it seems like it is correct code. In fact it is the same as another component I written that works.

But for whatever reason the `addswing` value of the `addswingtypeform` is always undefined

I have no idea why.

Is there any clue of what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to the following and you can see the result.

Please replace your HTML code by following block of code.

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2">
<form (ngSubmit)="addswingtype()" #addswingtypeform="ngForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 mt-2">
            <input type="text"
            id="addswingtype"
            name="addswing"
            ngModel
            placeholder="Enter A Swing Type"
            class="form-control">

   </div>
   <div class="col-2 mt-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

And replace your TS code by following block of code.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
selector: 'app-swingerandhosttypes',
  templateUrl: './swingerandhosttypes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swingerandhosttypes.component.css'],
  providers: [Httpservice]
})
export class SwingerandhosttypesComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('addswingtypeform') addswingtypeform:NgForm;
  constructor(private http: Httpservice) { }

  addswingtype(){
     console.log(this.addswingtypeform);
     const url = swingtypeallorcreate;
     const payload = {
        name: this.addswingtypeform.form.value.addswing
     };
     this.http.post(url, payload)
      .subscribe(
        (req: any)=>{
          this.swingtypes.push(req);
     });
  }
```